# Emulator black screen

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator

I always get a blank screen in emulator. I have tried many things, but not getting result.

[image]

Comment: is this happens after particular seconds ?

Comment: No, this issue getting last 4 day's to. Can you please help me for this?

Comment: try to delete your .android folder inside of your `Users` file directory and try to download the emulator again

Answer (score -1):

try to press ctrl + p or cold boot the emulator